# How to suppress compiler warnings on incomplete pattern match

Tags: f#, pattern-matching

Ok, Ok - I know this is a **bad idea** in general. Nevertheless in a very specific context - Within my test cases I just expect a certain result and anything else would be an error in any way. And doing pattern matching simply obscures my test code.

Here an example

```
type Result =
     | Success of int * int
     | Error of String

let someFunc x : Result = // implementation not important here

// and then later in my test code

[<Test>]
member me.``Some Cool Test Method``() =
    let (Success x, y) = someFunc "Foo"
    equals x 1
    equals y 2
```

Any ideas on how to make that more pleasant and compiler friendly?

Comment: You should be able to use `--nowarn:YY` for the right number

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why don't you just write the test like this?

```
[<Test>]
member me.``Some Cool Test Method``() =
    let actual = someFunc "Foo"

    let expected = Success(1, 2)
    equals expected actual
```

This doesn't generate any warnings that you'll need to suppress.

Comment: This works pretty well if the DU is easily presentable as above. However if you have a DU embedded in another DU in another DU ... etc. Then constructing all these DUs becomes cumbersome and again starts hiding the intent of the test code. Specifically if for testing purposes you only need a few items that are not necessarily all within the same DU.

Answer (score 7):

You can disable the warning by inserting this line somewhere before the incomplete pattern-match:

```
#nowarn "0025"
```

I used this before also for some quick tests, most likely the scenario you describe.

The other option which is probably the one you refer by *doing pattern matching* is to catch-all other cases with the wildcard `_` and throw an error:

```
[<Test>]
member me.``Some Cool Test Method``() =
    match someFunc "Foo" with
    | (Success x, y) ->
        equals x 1
        equals y 2
    | _ -> failwith "unexpected value"
```

then the compiler will be *happy* and if you know it will never reach there you don't care to handle that error further because you know it will never be thrown.

Comment: The #nowarn flag will help for certain. Surrounding it with a match is exactly what I dont want as it hides the intent of my test code. Upvote for the #nowarn part thou

Comment: @robkuz Yes, that's why I said that it's probably what you refer by "doing pattern matching".